# RoR - Testing errors - expecting <"categories/new"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rendering

I have a problem with my app testing. It's been hanging around for too long now and I'm even wondering, why am I testing this at all (since outside the tests, it works perfectly!)??

So here's the errors:

> $ rake test 
>   Run options: --seed 1855
>
> `# Running:
>
> .F
>
> Failure:
>   CreateCategoriesTest#test_invalid_category_submission_results_in_failure
>   [/Users/user/Documents/ruby_project/rails_projects/alpha-blog/test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:17]:
>   expecting <"categories/new"> but rendering with <[]>
>
> bin/rails test test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:15
>
> F
>
> Failure:
>   CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category
>   [/Users/user/Documents/ruby_project/rails_projects/alpha-blog/test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:7]:
>   expecting <"categories/new"> but rendering with <[]>
>
> bin/rails test test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:5
>
> .........
>
> Finished in 0.638134s, 18.8048 runs/s, 25.0731 assertions/s. 12 runs,
>   16 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

The test looks like:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "get new category form and create category" do
    get new_category_path
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
    post categories_path, params: { category: {name: "sports"}}
    follow_redirect!
    end
    assert_template 'categories/index'
    assert_match 'sports', response.body
  end

  test "invalid category submission results in failure" do
    get new_category_path
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_no_difference 'Category.count' do
    post categories_path, params: { category: {name: " "}}
    end
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_select 'h3.panel-title'
    assert_select 'div.panel-body'
  end
end
```

and the controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_admin, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @categories = Category.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      flash[:success] = "La nueva categoria se creó correctamente"
      redirect_to categories_path
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
     @categories = Category.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end

  def require_admin
    if !logged_in? || logged_in? and !current_user.try(:admin?)
      flash[:danger] = "Solamente el admin puede acceder a esta seccion"
    redirect_to categories_path
    end
  end


end
```

Just to give you a few heads up on what I've done so far to resolve my problem (because it appeared before), I have replaced this portion of the "get new category form and create category":

```
post_via_redirect categories_path, category: {name: "sports"}
```

by:

```
post categories_path, params: { category: {name: "sports"}}
follow_redirect!
```

as for the "invalid category submission results in failure" test I replaced:

```
post categories_path, category: {name: " "}
```

by:

```
post categories_path, params: { category: {name: " "}}
```

and it worked before I placed a limitation to the use of the app (in the controller):

```
before_action :require_admin, except: [:index, :show]
[...]
  def require_admin
    if !logged_in? || logged_in? and !current_user.try(:admin?)
      flash[:danger] = "Solamente el admin puede acceder a esta seccion"
    redirect_to categories_path
    end
  end
```

Does anyone have any idea on what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I've got the answer to my question. Dumb me, I hadn't passed a user for these test and, obviously, by requiring a user the tests couldn't perform correctly anymore.

So here's the correction in the test helper file:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  def sign_in_as(user, password)
    post login_path, params: { session: {email: user.email, password: password}}
  end
end
```

and for the create_categories_test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        @user = User.create(username: "John", email: "john@example.com", password: "password", admin: true)
    end

  test "get new category form and create category" do
    sign_in_as(@user, "password")
    get new_category_path
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
    post categories_path, params: { category: {name: "sports"}}
    follow_redirect!
    end
    assert_template 'categories/index'
    assert_match 'sports', response.body
  end

  test "invalid category submission results in failure" do
    sign_in_as(@user, "password")
    get new_category_path
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_no_difference 'Category.count' do
    post categories_path, params: { category: {name: " "}}
    end
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_select 'h3.panel-title'
    assert_select 'div.panel-body'
  end
end
```

Sorry guys for the useless question and bothering!

Answer (score 0):

Mine is putting `expect` before `get :index`

Which should be

`get :index 
expect(response).to render_template(:index)`